# Escape without root privilege?

Tags: ubuntu, security, windows, virtualbox

I worried programs running on VMs escape from the Virtualbox to my host machine, but as I know most escape actions need to get the root privilege, so I'v never type root password when running 3rd parted programs, is that enough to make me avoid escape Vulnerability?

Comment: If you don't trust an application, don't run it.

Comment: Does a known vulnerability exist in current version of virtualbox that allows accessing the host? If yes, @roaima's comment applies. If no, you can safely use 3rd party programs as long as you're not a probable victim of a zero-day exploit and keep your software up to date.

Comment: @pLumo The question is perhaps looking at the problem a little too narrowly.  Am I aware of any specific malware that targets VMs only?  No.  Is some malware completely unaffected by being contained in a VM? Definitely, yes.  Attacks using the [heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) exploit only need outgoing TCP network connections which most VMs have.  As noted in my answer Specter and Meltdown not practically hindered.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that root access inside the VM is no guarantee.  It makes it more difficult for some forms of malware but not all.

My advice is assume everything un-trusted is guilty until proven innocent.  That is, assume everything un-trusted is definitely malicious, and be happy when you're proven wrong.

To that end I would review as much advice as you can on how to analyse known malware.  There is some good advice out there on the risks.  Having read some of this I'd say the general consensus seems to be that there *are* still risks.  Specific vectors of attack are / have been:

- worms that can jump from machine to machine across the network.  Your VM is most likely on the network and so is your host.  Remember your PC usually sits behind a firewall (even just a home router) which blocks a lot of attacks at the door.  Running a VM puts the malware on your network inside the firewall.
- CPU timing exploits exist.  See [Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability)) and [Specter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)). Even without escaping the VM there's a risk that this *type* of bug can give away secret information from your host.
- VM tools.  These are implicitly designed to give your VM access to features on the host and exploits may give more access than expected.  You don't normally *need* to install these, but if you do, they could be vulnerable.

---

**From your question and comments**

> but as I know most escape actions need to get the root privilege

"most" isn't a good word in security.

> If you don't trust an application, don't run it.

But then this is real life and that's not always an option.  But it's a reasonable rule of thumb.  If you are not deliberately trying to analyse malware then check the origin of what you install first.  Check it comes from a reputable source and do what you can to check how many people are using it / talking about it online.

---

**References for further reading (do read the full answers here!)**

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3060/10066

> VMs can definitely cross over. Usually you have them networked, so any malware with a network component (i.e. worms) will propagate to wherever their addressing/routing allows them to. Regular viruses tend to only operate in usermode, so while they couldn't communicate overtly, they could still set up a covert channel. If you are sharing CPUs, a busy process on one VM can effectively communicate state to another VM (that's your prototypical timing covert channel).

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3058/10066

> Nonetheless, it's pretty good. Probably most malware that you run across in the field won't have special code to escape from a VM.  And running the malware in a VM is certainly a lot safer than installing it directly onto your everyday work machine!

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23503/10066

> The few vulnerabilities I see these days are based more in the 'vmtools' portion. This is the software you install to make the guest OS run more efficiently (for VMWare this is what allows on the fly cursor capture, and sharing between guest and host without a network). This is a special software pathway for infection; don't install the tools, don't have the vulnerability.